# how to copy every 5th file/frame to a new folder in python scripts

Tags: python

right now i extract all the frames of a video into a folder with this

```
#convert video
def video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc):
    """Function to extract frames from input video file
    and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
    Args:
        input_loc: Input video file.
        output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
    Returns:
        None
    """
    try:
        os.mkdir(output_loc)
    except OSError:
        pass
    # Log the time
    time_start = time.time()
    # Start capturing the feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)
    # Find the number of frames
    video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
    print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)
    count = 0
    print ("Converting video..\n")
    # Start converting the video
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Extract the frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            continue
        # Write the results back to output location.
        cv2.imwrite(output_loc + "/%#03d.png" % (count+1), frame)
        count = count + 1
        # If there are no more frames left
        if (count > (video_length-1)):
            # Log the time again
            time_end = time.time()
            # Release the feed
            cap.release()
            # Print stats
            print ("Done extracting frames.\n%d frames extracted" % count)
            print ("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
            break
if __name__=="__main__":
    input_loc = args.videofile
    output_loc = data_path + '\\' + args.projectname + '_gen\\input_filtered'
    video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc)
```

but i also need an extra folder with every 3rth frame of the folder.

so for example the frames are named like this 001.png, 002.png, 003.png, 004.png, 005.png etc..

i want to copy frames 001.png, 004.png etc.. to a new folder

is there any way to do this automatically and make it so i can change the framegap number?
now it's 3 but i want to do other numbers too..

i'm using this right now as @michael suggested but it gets inconsistent with numbers for --framegap above 5 because I can't put 001 in 'for i in range'

```
import os
import shutil

print (" ")
print ("making frames with your --framegap value to gen_filtered folder")

train_filtered = data_path+'\\'+str(args.projectname)+'_train'+'\\'+'input_filtered'
gen_filtered = data_path + '\\' + args.projectname + '_gen\\input_filtered'


video_length = len(os.listdir(gen_filtered))
print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)


if video_length <100:
    for i in range(1, 9, args.framegap):
        print (i)  
        shutil.copy2(gen_filtered+'\\'+'00'+str(i)+'.png', train_filtered)
    for i in range(10, video_length, args.framegap):
        print (i)  
        shutil.copy2(gen_filtered+'\\'+'0'+str(i)+'.png', train_filtered)
        
if video_length >100:
    for i in range(1, 9, args.framegap):
        print (i)  
        shutil.copy2(gen_filtered+'\\'+'00'+str(i)+'.png', train_filtered)
    for i in range(10, 99, args.framegap):
        print (i)  
        shutil.copy2(gen_filtered+'\\'+'0'+str(i)+'.png', train_filtered)
    for i in range(100, video_length, args.framegap):
        print (i)  
        shutil.copy2(gen_filtered+'\\'+str(i)+'.png', train_filtered)
print ("exported all frames to " "gen_filtered")
```

Comment: "range" can produce integers with a defined step (e. g. 3) to yield 1, 4, 7,... Strings have the method "format" to convert the int into a filename. Module "shutil" contains functions to copy files easily. You have to write such a functionality yourself or maybe find it in an external library.

Comment: The easy way is `if count % 3 == 1:` then write to the second folder.

Comment: @michael it worked with some tweaking but it starts being inaccurate above 10 because had to make some changes because apparently i can't use 001 i have to use 1, any fix for that?

Comment: String objects have the "format" method for string formatting with its own [mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. Basically just dividing the count by a user-provided framegap to determine if you should write to the other output location as well. Added the count = 0 base case since it seems like you want to copy the first file in your example

```py
#convert video
def video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc, framegap, other_output_loc):
    """Function to extract frames from input video file
    and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
    Args:
        input_loc: Input video file.
        output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
    Returns:
        None
    """
    try:
        os.mkdir(output_loc)
    except OSError:
        pass
    # Log the time
    time_start = time.time()
    # Start capturing the feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)
    # Find the number of frames
    video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
    print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)
    count = 0
    print ("Converting video..\n")
    # Start converting the video
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Extract the frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            continue
        # Write the results back to output location.
        cv2.imwrite(output_loc + "/%#03d.png" % (count+1), frame)

        # if our count is divisible by the framegap, copy to other folder location
        if count % framegap == 0 or count == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(other_output_loc + "/%#03d.png" % (count+1), frame)        
        count = count + 1

        # If there are no more frames left
        if (count > (video_length-1)):
            # Log the time again
            time_end = time.time()
            # Release the feed
            cap.release()
            # Print stats
            print ("Done extracting frames.\n%d frames extracted" % count)
            print ("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
            break
if __name__=="__main__":
    input_loc = args.videofile
    output_loc = data_path + '\\' + args.projectname + '_gen\\input_filtered'
    video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc)
```

Comment: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'

Comment: @NicolaiNightVision - looks like I added an extra comma in there